# How to decorate and overwrite all functions in a R local package

Tags: r

I have developed a local package with 150+ functions and would like to build a dictionary of input/output formats (mostly nested tibbles) over all functions.

Since I have testthat tests written, I would like to decorate every function of the package with:

```
write_in_out_formats_decorator <- function(f){
    wrapper <- function(...) {
        res <- f(...)

        # Write arguments and results formats in some files

        return(res)
    }
    return(wrapper)
}
```

Then I would run my tests and retrieve all the format files.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to decorate my functions inside a testthat context.

I tried the package tinsel : https://github.com/nteetor/tinsel
but the `source_decoratees` function does not seem to do the trick since testthat runs tests using the functions from package namespace and source functions are not taken into account.

So I thought about something in a setup.R before tests run:

```
for (funcname in package_funcnames) {
    func <- get(funcname, envir = asNamespace(my_package))

    # decorate my function here
    decorated_func <- func ...

    assignInNamespace(funcname, decorated_func, ns = my_package)
}
```

I have tried several things like creating a helper namespace to store my original functions and have:

```
decorated_func <- write_in_out_formats_decorator(helper_ns::func)
```

No success so far... I feel a bit lost.

Would someone have an idea of how this can be done?

Comment: Where exactly are you having issues? The approach that you've shown as code will work, you just need to ensure that the code is run before tests are run (and after your package is loaded), e.g. inside a `tests/testthat/helper-*.r` file. You might also have to unlock your namespace to ensure this still works if the tests are run inside `R CMD check` (not sure that's necessary). But, honestly, I wouldn't recommend this; instead, I'd probably put the decorates functions into a separate environment and explicitly refer to that in my tests.

Comment: Oh after some further testing I realised that the problem I am left with now is that furrr functions I use cannot find the functions I call in the helper_namespace. I investigate that now. Regarding your suggestion, is it possible to define a test context that specifies the namespace in which to search the functions? I could then have the same testfiles executed in two contexts : 1/ the functions are searched in the package environment, 2/ ...in the decorated environment. I guess I should read some documentation now.

Comment: There's no such mechanism, but you could of course simply `attach()` your decorated-functions environment before the tests are run. However, I meant this much more literally: inside your test cases, instead of `foo()`, you'd call your functions via `myenv$foo()`. There's nothing in 'testthat' that mandates that you call your package's functions directly.

Comment: It works well and is much cleaner this way! I just have to find a way to have furrr aware of my decorated functions namespace now. Another topic. Thanks again Konrad.